# How to pass parameters retrieved from form submit as arguments to a function in django

Tags: django, django-models, django-forms, django-views, django-urls

I have just started learning django. I created a form from django models. On the click of submit button the data is getting stored in database. Now what i want is something like the one given below :

```
#view.py
def contact(request):
  if request.method == 'POST':
  form = UserForm(request.POST)
  if form.is_valid():
            user = form.save()
            return HttpResponseRedirect("/contact/create_db")

#urls.py
(r'^contact/$', views.contact),
(r'^contact/create_db$', views.do_create),
```

Now when i define do_create function in views.py i want to pass the arguments(user data of user form) like this:

```
def do_create(request, password, dbname, admin_password, confirm_password, demo_data=False, language=None, **kw):
```

Is this possible using django. How can this be achieved.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

All you're asking here is how to get the value of the saved `user` in a subsequent view.

Well, this is easy. Once the user is saved, it (like any model instance) gets a `pk` value. You can use this in the URL for the subsequent view.

```
url(r'^contact/create_db/(?P<user_id>\d+)/$', views.do_create, 'do_create'),
```

In `contact`:

```
from django.shortcuts import redirect

...

user = form.save()
return redirect('do_create', kwargs={'user_id': user.pk})
```

And in `do_create`:

```
def do_create(request, user_id):
    user = User.objects.get(pk=user_id)
```

Note the way I've passed in the URL name and arguments into `redirect`, rather than hard-coding the URL.

Answer (score 1):

You don't need to pass them into a view. You want to pass them into a form. And you are already doing this:

```
form = UserForm(request.POST)
```

You pass your POST data into the form. If you want to do something with this data, use `form.cleaned_data` dictionary after form validation. Reading [docs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/forms/) is also a good idea.

Comment: Acutally My question is how can i retrieve a submitted data in another function not in the same function. Note that in return HttpResponseRedirect("/contact/create_db")
create_db in urls.py will use another function called do_create. It is in this do_create funtion where i will retrieve my submitted data.Sorry for my english

Comment: @user1053786 You don't need a redirect here. Do the saving stuff in `form.save` method.